# How to diagnose DRAKE TR7 power problem

Tags: power-supply, repair

My son was recently gifted a vintage DRAKE TR7 ham radio.  It's been "in the attic" for 20+ years.  When we try to power it up, the (separate) power supply turns on and we have checked with a multi-meter that the radio itself is getting power.  But nothing on the face of the receiver comes on.  Looking for suggestions on what to test next (and how).  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Owner's manual. You might try connecting an antenna to it, and see if you can hear sounds coming out the speaker with the volume and RF gain turned up. But if the digital readout is dark, something else may be wrong

Here is the [Drake TR7 service manual](http://www.qsl.net/4/4x6on/RADIO%20MANUALS/MISCELLANEOUS/DRAKE--TR-7-Service-Manual.pdf), as well as the [Owner's manual](http://www.wb4hfn.com/DRAKE/DrakeManuals/TR7/Manual_TR7.htm).